# How i can draw new lines with convas js

Tags: javascript, canvas

i want to draw lines with convas  but my previous lines was deleted when i try create a new line. I wark with convas the first time and i will be happy if you can say me about my mistakes and solutions of the problem

```
        const convas = document.querySelector(".v");
        const ctx = convas.getContext("2d");
    
        let startPositionLine = { x: 0, y: 0 };
        let endPositionLine = { x: 0, y: 0 };
        let { xStart, yStart } = startPositionLine;
        let { xEnd, yEnd } = endPositionLine;
    
        function moveMouseEvent(e) {
        xEnd = e.offsetX;
        yEnd = e.offsetY;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, convas.width, convas.height);
        ctx.moveTo(xStart, yStart);
        ctx.lineTo(xEnd, yEnd);
        ctx.stroke();
      }
    
        convas.onmousedown = (e) => {
        ctx.beginPath();
        xStart = e.offsetX;
        yStart = e.offsetY;
        ctx.stroke();
        convas.onmousemove = (e) => moveMouseEvent(e);
      };
       convas.onmouseup = () => {
       convas.onmousemove = null;
      };
```

Comment: You are drawing in the `function moveMouseEvent` there you have `clearRect` that will clear everything

Comment: Since you have to clear the canvas everytime you move the mouse, You will need to save the start and end x &  y coordinates of each line you draw to an array as you draw them.  Then after `ctx.stroke();` you loop the array to redraw each line saved in the array.  So in the arrray you will be saving you Xstart, Ystart, xEnd, Yend each time you click the canvas.  You will also need to set up a variable switch to know whether to save the start or end coordinates for each click / mousedown event.

Answer (score 0):

I mentioned this in my comment to your post above, but thought I would just give an example you can run and test here. So you are correct in what you are doing, but you just need to save each drawn line to an array AS YOU DRAW THEM. You will see the code for this in the mousedown event handler here. Then you need to redraw those saved lines each time after you clear the canvas in mousemove event handler.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var canvasrect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
var Xstart = 0;
var Ystart = 0;
var Xend = 0
var Yend = 0
var isDrawing = false;
var linesArray = [{}];


// MOUSE CLICK / BUTTON DOWN LISTENER
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  canvasrect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

  Xstart = e.clientX - canvasrect.left;
  Ystart = e.clientY - canvasrect.top;


  // We need to know if the user is actuallydrawing or not.
  // Each time the user clicks their canvas we toggle whether to start or stop drawing.
  if (isDrawing) {
    // If this is the end of a line, save the end coordinates to the latest array element.
    linesArray[linesArray.length - 1].xe = Xend;
    linesArray[linesArray.length - 1].ye = Yend;
    isDrawing = false;
  } else {
    // If this is the start of a new line, save the start coordinates in a new array element along with end coordinate placeholders.
    linesArray.push({
      xs: Xstart,
      ys: Ystart,
      xe: 0,
      ye: 0
    })
    isDrawing = true;
  }
});


// MOUSE MOVE
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  // get the current mouse x & y locations along with any scrolling and window resizing offsets.
  Xend = e.clientX - canvasrect.left;
  Yend = e.clientY - canvasrect.top;

  if (isDrawing === true) {

    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    //clear the canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasrect.width, canvasrect.height);

    // Draw a line from the initial click coordinates to the current mouse pointer coordinates.
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#fe0101';
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(Xstart, Ystart);
    ctx.lineTo(Xend, Yend);
    ctx.stroke();

    // now redraw the previous lines saved in the linesArray
    if (linesArray.length >= 1) {
      for (let i = 0; i < linesArray.length; i++) {
        if (linesArray[i].xe != 0) {
          ctx.strokeStyle = '#fe0101';
          ctx.lineWidth = 3;
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.moveTo(linesArray[i].xs, linesArray[i].ys);
          ctx.lineTo(linesArray[i].xe, linesArray[i].ye);
          ctx.stroke();
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500" style="background-color:lightGray"></canvas>
```